# Can time.time() be used in a way so it records split times while running a python3 program?

Tags: python-3.x, performance, optimization, time, runtime

I am looking to record the instance of a program during specific periods of its runtime i.e let's say the program runs for 10 seconds but I want to record it's instance/results that it produces at 3 secs and 8 seconds. Can time.time() be used to achieve this in python? Is there any other alternative to do the same?

Comment: So, you want to take a screen shot of the program's state during execution at 3, 8, whatever arbitrary seconds you choose, and inspect it's progress as of that point? Is this for debug purposes or do you actually want to track the program's progress for some other purpose (i.e. a loading bar)?

Comment: I actually want to track the program's progress. It is a hill climbing algorithm. I want to track how close it is getting to the target.